# change Link at Wordpress behind the shown IP on the comment list - column_author

Tags: php, wordpress, function, hook

Hi Cracks and Professions,

at the Dashboard in Wordpress we had a list of all given comments which are shown at `yourDomain.com/wp-admin/edit-comments.php`

We can see all Information about the comment author the first column - as $comment_author

There's a shown URL behind the author IP, wich i had to change - i think so, best with a function.

**Any hint, ideas or solutions** how i can change the actuall give URL:

- `yourDomain.com/wp-admin/edit-comments.php?s=127.0.0.1&mode=detail`

*… into an URL like this …*

- http://www.mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=blacklist%3a127.0.0.1

*… where the 127.0.0.1 is the IP from comment_author!*

ps.:
Sorry, for my lousy english, but i hope it's god enough to understand me?!

Comment: Would be nice if you added your Dashboard widget code... Also, please note that WordPress has his own Stack: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I looked pretty hard for a pure PHP way to do this by using hooks but I don't think there is one.  Most of the HTML in the comments table is output via echo in the file `wp-admin/includes/class-wp-comments-list-table.php` which could easily be extended, but I didn't see a way to instruct Wordpress to load the extended class.

Anyway, here is a Wordpress plugin that registers a hook in `admin_footer` which outputs some Javascript if the page being viewed is `edit-comments.php`.

You can put this in a `.php` file and add it to your `wp-content/plugins` folder.  Go to WP Admin, and activate the plugin.  I called it `Comment IP Address Blacklist Lookup`.

Here's the code.  I don't plan on doing anything with it so I release it as GPL code.  Feel free to ask for help or suggest any improvements.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Comment IP Address Blacklist Lookup
Plugin URI: http://example.com
Description: Changes the IP address link in the comment list to MXToolbox.com's blacklist check
Author: Drew Phillips
Version: 0.1
Author URI: https://www.drew.co.il
*/

/*  Copyright (C) 2012 Drew Phillips

This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
(at your option) any later version.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307  USA
*/

require_once ABSPATH . '/wp-includes/pluggable.php';

// Admin menu and admin functions below...

add_action('admin_footer', 'replace_admin_footer');

function replace_admin_footer()
{
    if (basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) == 'edit-comments.php') {
        echo <<<EOD
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function replace_comments()
    {
        var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        var i, link, match;

        for (i in links) {
            link = links[i];

            if ( null != (match = link.href.match(/edit-comments\.php\?s=(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)&mode=detail/))) {
                link.href = "http://www.mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=blacklist:" + match[1];
                link.target = "_blank";
            }
        }

    }

    replace_comments();
-->
EOD;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome glad to help, thanks for offering the bounty.  Been a while since I've done a WP plugin so that was fun to look at again.